# Unable to register in the Registration(Table not getting inserted)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have tried to create registration and a login page.But when I am trying to register,the field values are not getting inserted.This is my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.login1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

    Button mLogin;
    Button mRegister;

    EditText muname;
    EditText mpassword;

    DBHelper DB = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.login:

            muname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ledituname);
            mpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Leditpw);

            String username = muname.getText().toString();
            String password = mpassword.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || username == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (password.equals("") || password == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                boolean validLogin = validateLogin(username, password,
                        getBaseContext());
                if (validLogin) {
                    // System.out.println("In Valid");
                    //Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TabBar.class);
                    // in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
                    //startActivity(in);
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Welcome.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Success Valid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    startActivity(i1);
                    // finish();
                }
            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password,
            Context baseContext) {
        DB = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] columns = { "_id" };

        String selection = "username=? AND password=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { username, password };

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            cursor = db.query(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

        if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User Name and Password miss match..\nPlease Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        DB.close();
    }
}
```

Registration.java

```
package com.example.login1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener  
{
    private Button mSubmit;
    private Button mCancel;

    private EditText mFname;
    private EditText mLname;
    private Spinner mGender;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPhno;
    private EditText mAdd;
    private EditText mBloodGroup;
    private EditText mDob;
    private EditText mFatherName;
    private EditText mMotherName;
    private EditText mUsername;
    private EditText mpass;
    private EditText mcpass;

    private String Gen;

      protected DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

         // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        mFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.efname);
        mLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elname);
        mGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eemail);
        mPhno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ephnno);
        mAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eadd);
        mBloodGroup = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebloodGroup);
        mDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edob);
        mFatherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eFatherName);
        mMotherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMotherName);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eusername);
        mpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epass);
        mcpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecpass);

        // Spinner method to read the on selected value
        ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] {
                        new State("Male"), new State("Female") });
        mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    } 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.cancel:
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // finish();
                break;

            case R.id.submit:

                 String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
                 String lname = mLname.getText().toString();
                 String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                 String phoneno = mPhno.getText().toString();

                 String address = mAdd.getText().toString();
                 String bloodgroup = mBloodGroup.getText().toString();
                 String dob = mDob.getText().toString();
                 String father = mFatherName.getText().toString();

                 String mother = mMotherName.getText().toString();
                 String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                 String password = mpass.getText().toString();
                 String cpassword= mcpass.getText().toString();

                boolean invalid = false;

                if (fname.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else

                if (lname.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else

                if (email.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else

                if (phoneno.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else if (address.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } 
                else if (bloodgroup.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (dob.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (father.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (mother.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (username.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (password.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (cpassword.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                else if (invalid == false) {
                    addEntry(fname, lname, Gen, email,phoneno,address,bloodgroup,dob,father,mother,username,password,cpassword);
                    Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i_register);
                    // finish();
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            DB.close();
        }

        private void addEntry(String fname, String lname, String Gen, String email,String phoneno, String address,String bloodgroup,String dob,String father,String mother,String username,String password,String cpassword) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("firstname", fname);
            values.put("lastname", lname);
            values.put("gender", Gen);
            values.put("email", email);
            values.put("username", phoneno);
            values.put("password", address);
            values.put("phoneno", bloodgroup);
            values.put("lastname", dob);
            values.put("gender", father);
            values.put("email", mother);
            values.put("username", username);
            values.put("password", password);
            values.put("phoneno", cpassword);

            try {
                db.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "your details submitted Successfully...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
            State st = (State) mGender.getSelectedItem();

            // Show it via a toast
            toastState("onItemSelected", st);
        }

        public void toastState(String name, State st) {
            if (st != null) {
                Gen = st.name;
                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.login1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
     private SQLiteDatabase db;
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
        public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lastname";
        public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
        public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phoneno";

        public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
        public static final String KEY_BLOODGROUP= "bloodgroup";
        public static final String KEY_DOB= "dob";
        public static final String KEY_FATHER= "father";
        public static final String KEY_MOTHER= "mother";
        public static final String KEY_USERNAME= "username";
        public static final String KEY_PASS= "pass";
        public static final String KEY_CPASS= "cpass";

        DBHelper DB = null;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "igate.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "igate1";

        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL, phoneno TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL,bloodgroup TEXT NOT NULL, dob TEXT NOT NULL,father TEXT NOT NULL, mother TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL, cpass TEXT NOT NULL );";

        public DBHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            System.out.println("In constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {

                db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public Cursor rawQuery(String string, String[] strings) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void open() {

            getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public Cursor getDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
        {

            Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_GENDER,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PHONE,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_BLOODGROUP,
                    KEY_DOB,KEY_FATHER,KEY_MOTHER,KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + text, null, null, null, null,
                    null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;

        }
}
```

State.java

```
package com.example.login1;

public class State 
{
     public String name;

        public State(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
}
```

Logcat

```
06-27 02:35:16.910: E/SQLiteLog(1393): (1) table igate1 has no column named password
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393): Error inserting gender=f lastname=f username=f firstname=f password=f email=f phoneno=f
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table igate1 has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO igate1(gender,lastname,username,firstname,password,email,phoneno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at com.example.login1.Registration.addEntry(Registration.java:215)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at com.example.login1.Registration.onClick(Registration.java:180)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-27 02:35:16.930: E/SQLiteDatabase(1393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help......

I have tried whatever suggestions give...but now i m getting this error

Logcat(my 2nd Logcat)

```
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): Process: com.example.login1, PID: 1581
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.example.login1.MainActivity.validateLogin(MainActivity.java:113)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.example.login1.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-27 04:23:42.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: too much code, please only post the relevant code.

Comment: Error :
 `String selection = "username=? AND password=?";` change to **`pass`**

Comment: Answered with working code, please check and mark as correct if i have answered correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Error says clearly: `table igate1 has no column named password.`

Your Create query is:

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL, phoneno TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL,bloodgroup TEXT NOT NULL, dob TEXT NOT NULL,father TEXT NOT NULL, mother TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL, cpass TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

And there are fields `pass` and `cpass`, not `password`.

Change that, and you're done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have thried to followup ur ur suggestions..But i am still facing probem..I have posted my Logcat(my 2nd Logcat).Can you please check it once

Comment: @user3736518 What is line MainActivity.java:113? You have something null on that line. Show that line.

Comment: Its `int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();` so your cursor is not having any data. That's why you are getting null pointer exception. Are you sure you have data in table? @user3736518

Comment: int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

        if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User Name and Password miss match..\nPlease Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

Comment: No. Check why cursor is not having data? Is there record in table? @user3736518

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious in the logcat:

> SQLiteException: table igate1 has no column named password

You declared the field as:

> public static final String KEY_PASS= "pass";

But you are trying to insert in the column "password":

> values.put("password", password);

Why not use the column name constants declared in DBHelper?

Comment: I have thried to followup ur ur suggestions..But i am still facing probem..I have posted my Logcat(my 2nd Logcat).Can you please check it once

Answer (score 0):

Create Table String :

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL, phoneno TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL,bloodgroup TEXT NOT NULL, dob TEXT NOT NULL,father TEXT NOT NULL, mother TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL, cpass TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

If you check out your create table string, the field is called `pass`. However when you are inserting the values, you are using "password" as the key. You need to ensure that when you use ContentValues to insert values into the database the key is same as the column name of the table.

```
values.put("lastname", lname);
values.put("gender", Gen);
...
values.put("password", address);
```

Also, if you put values with the same key multiple times, only the last value will be saved. So, ensure that you do not use the same key twice.

In your case, you're using `"password"` and `"phoneno"` keys twice. Even though this wont show up as a crash, it could be a cause for concern later on.

Comment: I have thried  to followup ur ur suggestions..But i am still facing probem..I have posted my Logcat(my 2nd Logcat).Can you please check it once

Comment: So, the previous problem is solved. The current problem is a Null Pointer Exception at com.example.login1.MainActivity.validateLogin(MainActivity.java:113). Can you point which line is 113 ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you just confused table column name in this line

```
values.put("password", address);
```

May be it must look like

```
values.put("address", address);
```

Check others column names. You have other typos ("password" insted of "pass" etc).
Also, you have string constant for column names. Use it to prevent such errors.

```
   private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
                    + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
                    + "("
                    + KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + KEY_FNAME  +"TEXT NOT NULL, ....
```

and

```
values.put(DBHelper.KEY_FNAME, fname);
```

Comment: I have thried to followup ur ur suggestions..But i am still facing probem..I have posted my Logcat(my 2nd Logcat).Can you please check it once

Answer (score 0):

Hey There are two changes with your code...

first one is that you are using

```
String selection = "username=? AND password=?"; // change to pass
```

Second : wrong fields names :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("firstname", fname);
values.put("lastname", lname);
values.put("gender", Gen);
values.put("email", email);
values.put("username", phoneno);
values.put("password", address);
values.put("phoneno", bloodgroup);
values.put("lastname", dob);
values.put("gender", father);
values.put("email", mother);
values.put("username", username);
values.put("password", password);
values.put("phoneno", cpassword);
```

**User valid fields there..**

This may help you to solve your error..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is discrepancy between the  Registration.java --> addEntry() method 
and the DB Helper. Please vote or mark the answer if it answers your question.

[image]

[image]

Complete Working Code as below,

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button mLogin;
    Button mRegister;

    EditText muname;
    EditText mpassword;

    DBHelper DB = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.login:

            muname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ledituname);
            mpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Leditpw);

            String username = muname.getText().toString();
            String password = mpassword.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || username == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (password.equals("") || password == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                boolean validLogin = validateLogin(username, password,
                        getBaseContext());
                if (validLogin) {
                    // System.out.println("In Valid");
                    //Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TabBar.class);
                    // in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
                    //startActivity(in);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Success Valid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    // finish();
                }
            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password,
            Context baseContext) {
        DB = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] columns = { "_id" };

        String selection = "username=? AND pass=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { username, password };

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            cursor = db.query(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

        if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User Name and Password miss match..\nPlease Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        DB.close();
    }
}
```

Registration.java

```
package com.example.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener  
{
    private Button mSubmit;
    private Button mCancel;

    private EditText mFname;
    private EditText mLname;
    private Spinner mGender;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPhno;
    private EditText mAdd;
    private EditText mBloodGroup;
    private EditText mDob;
    private EditText mFatherName;
    private EditText mMotherName;
    private EditText mUsername;
    private EditText mpass;
    private EditText mcpass;

    private String Gen;

      protected DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

         // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        mFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.efname);
        mLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elname);
        mGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eemail);
        mPhno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ephnno);
        mAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eadd);
        mBloodGroup = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebloodGroup);
        mDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edob);
        mFatherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eFatherName);
        mMotherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMotherName);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eusername);
        mpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epass);
        mcpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecpass);

        // Spinner method to read the on selected value
        ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] {
                        new State("Male"), new State("Female") });
        mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    } 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.cancel:
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // finish();
                break;

            case R.id.submit:

                 String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
                 String lname = mLname.getText().toString();
                 String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                 String phoneno = mPhno.getText().toString();

                 String address = mAdd.getText().toString();
                 String bloodgroup = mBloodGroup.getText().toString();
                 String dob = mDob.getText().toString();
                 String father = mFatherName.getText().toString();

                 String mother = mMotherName.getText().toString();
                 String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                 String password = mpass.getText().toString();
                 String cpassword= mcpass.getText().toString();

                boolean invalid = false;

                if (fname.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else

                if (lname.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else

                if (email.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else

                if (phoneno.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else if (address.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } 
                else if (bloodgroup.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (dob.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (father.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (mother.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (username.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (password.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (cpassword.equals("")) {
                    invalid = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                else if (invalid == false) {
                    addEntry(fname, lname, Gen, email,phoneno,address,bloodgroup,dob,father,mother,username,password,cpassword);
                    Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i_register);
                    // finish();
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            DB.close();
        }

        private void addEntry(String fname, String lname, String Gen, String email,String phoneno, String address,String bloodgroup,String dob,String father,String mother,String username,String password,String cpassword) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("firstname", fname); 
            values.put("lastname", lname); 
            values.put("gender", Gen); 
            values.put("email", email); 
            values.put("phoneno", phoneno); 
            values.put("address", address); 
            values.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup); 
            values.put("dob", dob); 
            values.put("father", father); 
            values.put("mother", mother); 
            values.put("username", username); 
            values.put("pass", password);
            values.put("cpass", cpassword);

            try {
                db.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "your details submitted Successfully...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
            State st = (State) mGender.getSelectedItem();

            // Show it via a toast
            toastState("onItemSelected", st);
        }

        public void toastState(String name, State st) {
            if (st != null) {
                Gen = st.name;
                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 

            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/efname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true">


        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/elname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rgender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eusernameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eusername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/epassText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ecpassText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm Password"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ecpass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ephnnoText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone Number"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ephnno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eaddText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ebloodGroupText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blood Group"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ebloodGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edobText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date of Birth"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="date" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eFatherNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Father Name"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eFatherName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eMotherNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mother Name"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eMotherName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submit"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.loginexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String KEY_USER = "username";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    //New Fields 
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phoneno";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_BLOODGROUP= "bloodgroup";
    public static final String KEY_DOB= "dob";
    public static final String KEY_FATHER= "father";
    public static final String KEY_MOTHER= "mother";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME= "username"; //Already Existing
    public static final String KEY_PASS= "pass";
    public static final String KEY_CPASS= "cpass";

    DBHelper DB = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "srikanth1.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "sri1";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
            + "("
            + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        System.out.println("In constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion < newVersion)
        {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME+ " RENAME TO "+DATABASE_TABLE_NAME+"_BK");

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                    + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
                    + "("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL, phoneno TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL,bloodgroup TEXT NOT NULL, dob TEXT NOT NULL,father TEXT NOT NULL, mother TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL, cpass TEXT NOT NULL );");
        }

    }

    public Cursor rawQuery(String string, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void open() {

        getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public Cursor getDetails(String text) throws SQLException {


        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_GENDER,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PHONE,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_BLOODGROUP,
                KEY_DOB,KEY_FATHER,KEY_MOTHER,KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + text, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

}
```